# How to access step over Signature Pad ActiveX object in chrome through javascript?

Tags: javascript, signature, clsid

This step over signature pad does not work in Google Chrome, but it works with IE.

```html
<div style="border: solid 1px blue; width:97%">
    <object id="signDevice" width="850" height="200" classid="CLSID:F5C74079-C195-4DA9-B60D-F6F5365042D1"></object>
    <br />
    <input id="btnStartSign" type="button" value="start" onclick="return StartCapture()"></input>
    <input id="btnStopSign" type="button" value="save" onclick="return StopCapture()"></input>
    @*<input id="btnShowBase64" type="button" value="sign base 64" onclick="return GetImageBase64()"></input>*@
    <input id="btnUploadSign" type="button" value="update" onclick="return SaveSign()"></input>
</div>
```

I think I will change CLSID.

Comment: Chrome does not support ActiveX